# Type of following statements in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I am having troubles with correct understanding of those types:

for:

```
int* j;
int** k;
```

1. `*j`
2. `&j`
3. `**j`
4. `*&j`
5. `*k`
6. `&k`
7. `**k`
8. `*&k`
9. `&*k`

My thoughts:

1. `int**` - double int pointer?
2. address for `j` pointer - whats the type of address? (Hexadecimal value)
3. `int***` ?
4. pointer, pointing to an address of `j` pointer ?
5. `int***`
6. address to double pointer `k`
7. `int****`
8. ?
9. ?

Comment: `*` in declarations in used to declare pointer, but in statements it can be used to dereference a pointer to invoke multiplication operator. So 1) `*j` given that type of `j` is `int *` will produce `int &`. `&` in declarations is used to declare lvalue reference, but in statements it can be used to take address or to invoke *bitwise and* operator.

Comment: I suggest reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in?rq=1) and see where your understanding lies.

Comment: Hint: `int * j` means not only "`j` is an `int *`" but also "`* j` is an `int`". This is intentional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in comments `*` and `&` have different semantics depending if they appear in declarations or statements:

1. `*j` Dereferences `j`
2. `&j` Takes the address of `j`
3. `**j` Double dereferencing a single pointer (Error)
4. `*&j` Dereferences the address of `j` (equivalent to `j`)
5. `*k` Dereferences `k` (yields another pointer)
6. `&k` Takes the address of `k`
7. `**k` Double dereferences a double pointer (OK)
8. `*&k` Dereferences the address of `k` (equivalent to `k`)
9. `&*k` Takes the address of the dereferenced pointer

See a [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49abe679928444dd)

---

<sub>**Note:**</sub>

> address for j pointer - whats the type of address? (Hexadecimal value)

The *hexadecimal value* is only used as usual representation for pointers, otherwise these are just numbers / values. Hexadecimal doesn't qualify for a type, it's just a numerical representation.

Comment: Thanks for answer. So *& negates each other and the statement *&k =k is true? Also another question - We can only dereference x times the variable only if it has been referenced at least x times right? (Like, we can't double dereference, single pointer, but we are able to triple dereference 5th level pointer?)

Comment: @Piodo Regarding your additional question: Yes. Dereferencing a `int***` once yields a `int**` and twice yields a `int*`.